# type '_BroadcastStream<User>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<FirebaseUser>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, stream

I am trying to check if a user is logged via firebase which will determine the route of screens presented. Since updating to version 0.5.0 I have been presented with the above error.

I am checking the logging status via the below widget

```
Widget _getScreenId() {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserId = snapshot.data.uid;
          return HomeScreen();
        } else {
          return LoginScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

And init firebase with below method

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of

```dart
Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserId = snapshot.data.uid;
```

Try to do next:

```dart
    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
          stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              final UserData user = snapshot.data;
              if (user == null){
                return LoginScreen()
              }

              return Provider.value(
                value: snapshot.data,
                child: HomeScreen(),
              );
            } else {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        );
```

However, you will need to do an extra step which I actually recommend you, implement and authservice to map the FirebaseUser to your UserData.

```dart
class FirebaseAuthService implements AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  UserSystem _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return UserData(
        uid: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        photoUrl: user.photoURL,
        isVerified: user.emailVerified);
  }

  @override
  Stream<UserData> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }
}
```

And of course, this is optional, add an Abstract class where you can manage and define all your methods. Facebook, Google, EmailAndPassword.

```dart
abstract class AuthService {
  Future<UserData> currentUserSystem();
  Future<UserData> signInAnonymously();
  Future<UserData> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<UserData> signInWithGoogle();
  Future<UserData> signInWithFacebook();
  Future<void> signOut();
  Stream<UserData> get onAuthStateChanged;
  void dispose();
}
```

Let me know if this helps!